# Use and necessity of pthread_attr_init()

Tags: unix, pthreads, posix

I just created one c program to create `threads` using POSIX thread library functions.I didn't use `pthread_attr_init()` function in that. Even my program works fine.So, what is the use of `pthread_attr_init()` and what does it do...? I am not familiar in thread concepts.Can anyone tell me is it compulsory to use `pthread_attr_init()` in thread concept program..?

Comment: A tutorial is here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_attr_init` is used to initialise a thread attributes structure, which can then be passed to `pthread_create`.

If you are creating threads with default attributes, you pass a NULL pointer for the thread attributes argument to `pthread_init` and there is no need to initialise an attribute structure.

However, if you want to configure specific thread attributes, such as scheduling policy, priority, concurrency level, then you must use `pthread_attr_init` to initialise the attribute structure before manipulating it using the attribute accessors functions (`pthread_set...` and `pthread_get...`) and passing it to the `pthread_init` function.